# Not pop up input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 input fields that I want to display in the modal box after user clicks on submit button. Do I have to change the type for matrix to type="text" in javascript? If so, how can I do that?

```
<form><br>
<h1 style="text-align: center; color:red;">LOGIN</h1>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME" id="name"><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="matrixno" placeholder="MATRIX NO" id="matrix"><br><br><br>
<input id="myBtn" type="button" value="Submit" style="cursor:pointer; margin-right: 4.5cm; padding: 7px 16px;">
</form>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rudy94/86gyqyd6/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello check the below fiddle I hope you are looking for this. hope it helps

[pop up input demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/86gyqyd6/3/)

don't use `.value` for global variable in the first Place  because when you submit it or call It in any event then the value get lost

To Skip this I will suggest

1.Initialize the variable `var some = document.getElementById("someid");`

2.call the variable along with its value anywhere `var answer=some.value`
I am describing this below  for more further knowledge.

**#Working**

```js
var x = document.getElementById("name"); //global variable
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

btn.onclick = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
alert(x.value);
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME" id="name">
<input id="myBtn" type="button" value="Submit" style="cursor:pointer; margin-right: 4.5cm; padding: 7px 16px;">
```

**#Not Working**

```js
var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

btn.onclick = function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 alert(x);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME" id="name">
<input id="myBtn" type="button" value="Submit" style="cursor:pointer; margin-right: 4.5cm; padding: 7px 16px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to a small change here:

```
var x = document.getElementById("name"), y = document.getElementById("matrix");

btn.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = x.value;
  document.getElementById("show1").innerHTML = y.value;
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Access the value of the inputs after clicking the button not on document ready/page load. Also on show1 `style="colorw:white;"` to  `style="color:white;"`

Comment: Now that I've changed it, the system can't even pop up the modal box

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the type, you can simply access it's value property.
So:

```
var pass = document.getElementById("matrix").value;
```